# Returning string in PHP functions

Tags: php

I start learning PHP.

What's the problem with this code?

```
        <?php

          class Cat
          {
              public $isAlive= true;
              public $numLegs=4;
              public $name="";

              public function __construct($name)
              {
                  $this->name=$name;
              }

              public meow()
              {
                  return "Meow meow";
              }
          }

          $cat1=new Cat("CodeCat")

          echo $cat1->meow();
        ?>
```

How Can I return a string in php functions?

Comment: Fix your syntax errors, and everything should work.

Comment: A really useful thing to work with while learning PHP is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display

Answer (score 1):

You've missed word "**function**":

```
      public function meow()
      {
          return "Meow meow";
      }
```

and ;

```
$cat1=new Cat("CodeCat");
echo $cat1->meow();
```

You should learn PHP more attentively